# USD - Pass Data through FireRequestAction

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, unified-service-desk

I am stuck in this small issue and as I am new to Microsoft usd therefore I require a bit of help to go through this.

I am trying to pass data from my **Xaml.cs** code inside USD **Action Call** but I am unable to do it. I have tried many solutions, below are some.

```
Object actionData;
 actionData = "CustomerID =D*****-****-****-****-***********";
 actionData = GeneralFunctions.Serialize(actionData);
 FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs(USDHostedControl, USDAction, actionData));
```

I have also tried like below,

```
 actionData = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CustomerID", "D*****-****-****-****-***********" }};
  actionData = GeneralFunctions.Serialize(actionData);
  FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs(USDHostedControl, USDAction, actionData));
```

And inside my USD Action Call I am passing like this,

```
customerid=[[CustomerID]]
```

But unfortunately, none of it is working.
I hope anyone here can help me with this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var ctx= Context.GetContext();
var context = new Context(ctx);
context["CustomerID"] = "D*****-****-****-****-***********"";
FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs(USDHostedControl, USDAction, context));
```

And then inside your Action Call get the value using $Context.